# cypress upgrade 9.0 to 10.3 , missing executable cypress.exe

Tags: cypress

I upgraded from Cypress 9.0 to 10.3.0 with `Corporate Proxy . PS C:\CypressUpgrade10> node -v v12.14.1 PS C:\CypressUpgrade10> npm -v 6.13.4`

```
PS C:\CypressUpgrade10>
```

I download (from nexus) & installation seems to be success

`npx cypress -v Cypress binary version: 10.3.0 Electron version: 18.3.0` Bundled Node version: 16.13.2

But npx cypress verify or cypress run /open gives error as below & there is no Cypress.exe on Local

No version of Cypress is installed in: `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.0\Cypress`

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install

Cypress executable not found at: `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe`

Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19042) Cypress Version: 10.3.0

Missing any dependency or compatibility issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `npx cypress install`. This should fix your issue.

Comment: No luck , giving same error PS C:\CypressUpgrade10> node_modules\.bin\cypress open 
No version of Cypress is installed in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.0\Cypress

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install


Cypress executable not found at: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe


Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19042)
Cypress Version: 10.3.0

Comment: Assuming you have. `package.json` file with all the dependencies. Please delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file and then run the command `npm install`.

Comment: Tried fresh installation , it works for Cypress 9,0 , but when I do cypress 10.3.0 fresh installation, Exe file is not available in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe

Comment: Note: In my case on a fresh PC, with `npm install -D cypress` it wasn't working, but with `npx cypress install` it worked and I could successfully start cypress via `npx cypress open` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It works after updating Binary version to 0 & installing by npm install cypress@10.3.0